# React Slick Carousel

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slick.js

I'm trying to build an Item page with multiple images that can be flipped through. I use React and Slick Carousel. The page is fetching data correctly and the three dots of the carousel are displayed, but they're not displaying any images. Any ideas?

````
import { Box, CardContent, Card } from "@mui/material";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

const ItemDetail = () => {


  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  };

  return (
    <Card
      sx={{
        maxWidth: 600,
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderRadius: 0,
        flexDirection: "column",
      }}
    >
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {item.images.map((image) => (
          <div key={image.id}>
            <Box
              sx={{
                height: "100%",
                border: 1,
                borderColor: "border.main",
                objectFit: "cover",
              }}
              alt=""
              image={
                `URL` + item.images[0].image
              }
              onError={(e) => console.log("Error loading image", e)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </Slider>

      ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the image address to:

src={`URL${image.image}`}